# Trying to fill select box with Inputpicker plugin and JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, html-select

```
$('#src_prodline').inputpicker({ calling the plugin function
    fields:['id','code','description'],
    fieldText : 'description',
    fieldValue : 'code',        
    headShow: true,
    filterOpen: true,
    $.ajax({            
        url: 'item_action.php', //Calling the function
        type:"POST",
        data: {             
            btn_action:'src_prodline' //Set item_id and variable se
        }           
    });
});
```

In my console I got this error:

> SintaxError: missing : after property id

What's wrong with that and how can I fix it???

> UPDATE:

Creating a new php file it's working

```
$('#src_prodline').inputpicker({        
    fields:['id','code','desc'],
    fieldText : 'description',
    fieldValue : 'code',
    pagination: true,       
    limit: 5,
    headShow: true,
    filterOpen: true,               
    url: 'item_1.php',
    pageCurrent: 1      
});
```

BUT unfortunately this is not what I want because I got a PHP page with different functions and I call one of theme with a `$_POST['btn_action']`

Example:

```
if ($_POST['btn_action']=='src_prodline'){
   ...........
}
```

So, my problem is that I don't have idea how can I send this variable at PHP page without error.

-->LOOK the code above update<--

Do you have any idea how can I solve this?

> UPDATE Ver. 2.0

I fixed it adding the variable in the web address but I hate to do that:

```
url: 'item_action.php?r=src_prodline'
```

Now, it's working but if somebody has a better solution please let me know it.

Comment: `$('#src_prodline').inputpicker({ calling the plugin function` is that the actual code? If so presumably you're missing the `//` to demarcate the comment.. You also have placed a `$.ajax` call in the middle of the options object you initialise the `inputpicker()` with. That's never going to work.

Comment: `calling the plugin function` need to be commented.

Comment: Rory McCrossan I'll try to remove $.ajax call outside and I'll let you know if it will work

Comment: NO error but it doesn't working yet.